# Importing Libraries not working in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project that requires me to import a library, and I am doing it in eclipse. I have imported the library, and it doesn't seem to recognize that I have the library imported.

[My user libraries.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Cadp.png)

[The build path for the project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W5p3.png)

A picture of my java project. The part highlighted corresponds to the import statement.
[image]
How can I make it so that eclipse can see that I have the library imported?

I tried changing java versions and also changing the build path as well.

Comment: If you need any more screenshots, let me know

Comment: How did you "import" this library, exactly?

Comment: I downloaded the latest version from the opencv website, then I added the appropriate files into my user libraries. When making the new java project, I added the user library into my build path. Sorry if I am using the wrong term for the wrong thing, I am a little new to programming.

Comment: Putting something in the User Libraries does not automatically make it available to projects - you must add it to the "Libraries" section of the project "Build Path"

Comment: I have already, Should it be under classpath or modulepath? I've tried both and they both seem to not work, but if there is a right one I should put it in to be safe, then I would rather go for that one.

Comment: Delete your `module-info.java` file, if needed you can recreate it later via project right-click _Configure_ (or in `module-info.java` add the required `requires ...;` statement).

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below Dependency in pom.xml for importing the libraries.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0-0</version>
</dependency>
```